# Interbase xe7 - cannot restore

Tags: database, relational-database, interbase

I have a backup file in .gdb format from interbase7.1.
I have installed interbase server on my own machine, version is xe7.
I opened ibconsole.exe application. Tried to register new database with above mentioned backup file and it says: error on-disc data structure.
Let's exclude that file is corrupted: I have got that from State organisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download interbase restore app from supporting websites.

It fixes corrupted part of GDB file